# c# method override in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the latest weeks I played with Unity3d using c# as scripting language.
I never used before c# nor Unity3d, and I'm trying to understand how methods overriding works in Unity framework.
What wonders me is that I can extend the base class `MonoBehavior` and override methods such `Start ()`, `Update ()` and so on without to have to use the `override` keyword and the compiler does not complain about it!
Instead in a "normal" C# program I must use the `override` keyword or I get a compiler warning. For example:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public virtual void MyMethod () {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.MyMethod()");
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass {
    public override void MyMethod () {
        Console.WriteLine("SubClass.MyMethod()");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main ()  {
        SubClass obj = new SubClass ();
        obj.MyMethod ();
    }
}
```

instead in Unity I can simply do:

```
class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        // code...
    }
}
```

What happens behind the scenes? Does unity make use of "dynamic tricks" or what?

Comment: I would consider it as some kinda of reflection - of course "smart" reflection  - normal would cause performance issues.

Comment: I think your answer can be found here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/177245/how-does-unitys-built-in-event-system-work-behind.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `MonoBehavior` doesn't have a definition for `Update`. The runtime checks if a method called `Update` exists (using reflection), and then calls it if it does, but you are not overriding a base implementation

### Update

Since you asked for an example on how this was possible, I've made a sample here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UrpYkf

Comment: I wonder why they chose this approach instead of a empty method that can be overridden.

Comment: interesting! could you please provide a pseudo-code example of how it could works?

Comment: You'll have to ask their developers for the reasons behind their design decisions... but more likely to make it easy for non-developers (who might have a hard time undestanding OOP and overriding) to get started with scripting.

Comment: @daveoncode sure, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UrpYkf (not pseudocode, but an actual c# implementation on calling a method on a class which may not implement it)

Comment: btw... dotnetfiddle is an amazing tool... it has even intellisense, wow! :D

Comment: You also have [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/). Each has its limitations... I use one or another when I hit them (and whenever I hit both of them's, I fire up Visual Studio)... but yeah, they are great for small runnable samples. Most of my C# answers in StackOverflow include a working fiddle when applicable.

Comment: I was using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php before for simple tests/experiments, but it sucks compared to dotnetfiddle :D

Comment: @Aphelion Because then the engine would have to call the method even for classes that don't override it (well, they *could* check if it's not the default method when initializing, but then the performance is the same as the current approach). Maybe they felt interfaces were too advanced for beginners (more chances of messing things up, such as defining the method but not implementing the interface).

Comment: @Kroltan to me reflection is always slower. The base is a class, so it could be an empty virtual method which is always called. This should have no performance penalty at all. Or at least not as much as using reflection. Altough, the reflection result could be cached however still invoking the method using reflection should still be slower instead of calling it the traditional (virtual / inherited) method. However it is c++ so probably I am wrong after all ;).

Comment: @Aphelion I really haven't measured, but I think the slow part of reflection is looking for the method. Invoking one should (in theory) be minimally slower than a virtual call. Not sure if Unity has any kind of specific clr or jit optimizations, but if it does, it could actually just use `call` instead of `callvirt` (or even inline those calls) and it would be actually faster, once the method lookup is done. Again, I don't actually know if it does any of this, but it definitely could

Comment: @Aphelion I remember reading on a blog post somewhere that the "reflection" is done statically at compile time, and at runtime, there's just a simple lookup table based on the type in question. Calling reflected methods is indeed slower, but in this case the reflection is static and only the mapping is dynamic, skipping any reflection downsides.

Answer (score 2):

**Source** by [bunny83](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/6612/bunny83.html) at http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/177292/view.html

> Unity works a bit different. All those so called "events" are NOT
>   methods of the MonoBehaviour class. If you have a C# reflector you can
>   just view the class implementation by opening the UnityEngine.dll
>
> Unity is mainly written in c++ and therefore most magic happens in
>   native code. Unity uses reflection to determine, after your scripts
>   have been compiled, what of those "events" you've implemented and
>   remember that for this class. Unity only calls Update / LateUpdate /
>   OnGUI when it has been implemented.
>
> Another point where you can notice that is when you create a
>   MonoBehaviour class and don't implement any of those methods/events
>   Unity will remove the enabled checkbox from your script instance
>   because it doesn't contain any events that are affected by enabled.
>
> Some events are dispatched with their SendMessage function (like
>   OnCollisionEnter and such events).
>
> The documentation calls all events "Overridable Functions" but that's
>   not really true. If they were implemented as virtual function you
>   would have to use the override keyword or it wouldn't work.
>
> Here's the whole implementation of MonoBehaviour:

```
public class MonoBehaviour : Behaviour
 {
     public extern bool useGUILayout
     {
         get;
         set;
     }
     public extern MonoBehaviour();
     private extern void Internal_CancelInvokeAll();
     private extern bool Internal_IsInvokingAll();
     public extern void Invoke(string methodName, float time);
     public extern void InvokeRepeating(string methodName, float time, float repeatRate);
     public void CancelInvoke();
     public extern void CancelInvoke(string methodName);
     public extern bool IsInvoking(string methodName);
     public bool IsInvoking();
     public Coroutine StartCoroutine(IEnumerator routine);
     public extern Coroutine StartCoroutine_Auto(IEnumerator routine);
     public extern Coroutine StartCoroutine(string methodName, object value);
     public Coroutine StartCoroutine(string methodName);
     public extern void StopCoroutine(string methodName);
     public extern void StopAllCoroutines();
     public static void print(object message);
 }
```

> I removed all the external attributes since nearly every
>   method/property is mapped to a native function.
>
> btw. the mentioned C# events are delegates which are just some kind of
>   function pointers but a bit more complex ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are no Start, Update, Awake, etc declared in MonoBehaviour base class. That's why you don't write any Override keyword when you declare them. They will be called by Unity3D if they are implemented in your class, which can lead to performance improvements.